# How to check for 2 different format in a column using pandas to_datetime func?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to format a column with 2 different datetime format using to_datetime

```
...
28            4/30/2016 22:51
29            4/30/2016 22:48
...      
3595353    10/1/2016 00:11:02
3595354    10/1/2016 00:10:13
...
```

In order to read the CSV File i used `bike_df = pd.read_csv('Bike_Trips.csv')`

The two format is then defined for to_datetime `frmt1 = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'` and `frmt2 = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S'`

I then attempted to convert two different format by running these two code in succession

```
bike_df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(bike_df['starttime'], format = frmt1, errors = 'coerce')
bike_df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(bike_df['starttime'], format = frmt2, errors = 'coerce')
```

However when `errors = 'coerce'` is used the datetime changes but NaT is used as the format is different

```
29        2016-04-30 22:48:00
                  ...        
3595353                   NaT
```

however, when `error = 'ignored'` is used nothing changes

```
29            4/30/2016 22:48
                  ...        
3595353    10/1/2016 00:11:02
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Maybe assign the first one to a different Series and the second one to a different Series then combine with `fillna`  or `combine_first`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

1. The value of `errors` parameter can be `raise`, `coerce` or `ignore` (not `ignored` otherwise `raise` is used)
2. The `frmt2` is incorrect because contains `%I` for hours which should start from 01, not 00 as in your sample.

However fixing above does not give working solution.
But is not that OK for you to use pandas builtin functionality to parse datetimes?

```
bike_df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(bike_df['starttime'],
                                      infer_datetime_format=True)
```

where `infer_datetime_format` turns on guessing of format based on input data

~~~ UPDATE ~~~

I see the way to recognize using two different formats like this (note that I have tested it on 4 fake entries):

```
# 1) create new column temp_starttime 
# and store there datetimes recognized using first format
bike_df['temp_starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(bike_df['starttime'], format=frmt1, errors='coerce')
# 2) get not recognized rows
not_recongized = bike_df[bike_df.temp_starttime.isnull()]
# 3) inplace fill not recognized rows with values recognized using second format
bike_df['temp_starttime'].fillna(pnd.to_datetime(not_recongized['starttime'], format=frmt2, errors='coerce'), inplace=True)
# 4) delete starttime column
del bike_df['starttime']
# 5) inplace rename temp_starttime to starttime
bike_df.rename(columns={"temp_starttime": "starttime"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bellum your answer works perfectly! 

However if the data set is too large infer_datetime_format=True may take too long. Therefore, is it possible to use two different formats for converting?